# ApiException: 8 , while using Firebase SignInClient on real device. Missing Feature{name=auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, version=8} on emulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this exception , while clicking google logo  button , which authorize user's email. Also want to notice, that I'm getting ApiException:8 on real device(OnePlus 7T) and missing feature on emulator.

I've been trying:

Clear cache ;

Remove and put google json file in app package ;

Change SHA1 and SHA256 to correct values;

Having authorization in google services on real device.

My app have 0 already authenticate users;

web client id is correct.

get code more clearly.

create new project and import code,
but nothing helps me, and I'm getting same errors.

```
@GmailSignIn  private val signIn:BeginSignInRequest,
  @GmailSignUp private val signUp:BeginSignInRequest

// this variables are from viewmodel consctructor and they're replying for auth, if user have already authorized account he will signing in, else signing Up.
```

```
@Provides
@GmailSignIn
fun provideSignInRequest() = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
    .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
        BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
            .setSupported(true)
            .setServerClientId(ServerClient)
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
            .build()
    )
    .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
    .build()

@Provides
@GmailSignUp
fun provideSignUpRequest() = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
    .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
        BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
            .setSupported(true)
            .setServerClientId(ServerClient)
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
            .build()
    )
    .build()

// It's a realization for this annotations with using hilt.
```

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class GmailSignIn

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class GmailSignUp
```

```
// This functions are from viewModel,onetap function is replying for sending user's gmail data to another screen

suspend  fun gmailOneTapClient():IntentSender{
    val signInResult = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signIn).await()
              stateAuthWithGmail.emit(
                  AuthSignInResult(
                      successful = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signIn).await(),
                      errorMessage = null,
                      Loading = false
                  )
              )
              if(signInResult == null){
                  oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signUp).await()
                 stateAuthWithGmail.emit(
                      AuthSignInResult(
                          successful = oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signUp).await(),
                          errorMessage = null,
                          Loading = false
                      )
                  )
              }
     return signInResult.pendingIntent.intentSender
    }


// This function replying for gmail Authorization.

  fun gmailAuth(credential: AuthCredential){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            stateAuthWithGmail.emit(
                AuthSignInResult(
                    errorMessage = null,
                    Loading = true
                )
            )
                when(val result =authorizationRepository.gmailAuth(credential)){
                is GmailAuthorizationEvent.Error ->{
                    stateAuthWithGmail.emit(
                        AuthSignInResult(
                            errorMessage = result.errorMessage,
                            successful = null
                        )
                    )
                }
                    is GmailAuthorizationEvent.Success ->{
                        stateAuthWithGmail.emit(
                            AuthSignInResult(
                                errorMessage = null,
                                Loading = false,
                                successful = result.data
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    is GmailAuthorizationEvent.Loading ->{
                        stateAuthWithGmail.emit(
                            AuthSignInResult(
                                errorMessage = null,
                                successful = null,
                                Loading = true
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

```
// This launcher is used for getting IntentSender data in other screen, also want to say, that navigation composables are correct.

val launcherGmailSignIn = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
    ){
            activityResult ->
        if(activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            try {
                val credentials = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(
                    activityResult.data
                )
                val googleIdToken = credentials.googleIdToken
                val googleCred = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleIdToken,null)
            authorizationViewModel.gmailAuth(googleCred)
            }catch (e:ApiException){
               print(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
// This is navigation realization to get users data in other screen 

navigateToGoogleSignIn = {
                    navigationScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
                      launcherGmailSignIn.launch(
                            IntentSenderRequest.Builder(
                                authorizationViewModel.gmailOneTapClient()
                            ).build()
                        )
                        navController.navigate("news_screen")
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I'm not spotting the issue at first glance. The code looks good to me. Are you sure the user is authenticated with Google on the device?

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: @AlexMamo  I'm authorized in gmail on my phone, but I have don't have any authorize gmail in my app, And I'm trying to implement sign up by gmail

Comment: I'm not sure why are you using `signUpResult.toString()`, as you need to use the result as an object of type `BeginSignInResult`, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo, I tried more clearly check screenshoots below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XkgGly0lcZylhyaTZr0-Jd8WH-Yy9fiM/view?usp=share_link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pRc3_MuEmH3wfaQ5mNXhaNCRBXP0L0sq/view?usp=share_link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y-bmGZfJp33X4FbBYZME6AEuRP-Sfx8Q/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @AlexMamo, also I want to notice, that when I'm trying to launch my project on android Emulator (24 min sdk) , my app gives me this error

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-V_C_9iHTeyiBYmZsPM_vWVKtgW4gx8c/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image.

Comment: @DamiaFuentes error was with emulator.